# Cannot update ios app in Appstore connect

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes-store

im trying to update the version of our app.
And we have added privacy policy already...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4haA.png)

But still i can't submit for review. Apple asking me to provide a privacy policy. But its already there in app privacy section.
any idea to solve this.
[The error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXuug.png)

Comment: They're not asking for a policy URL, they're asking for your privacy practices, and there's a questionnaire there that you need to fill out - should be below the "Privacy URL" in your first screenshot.

Comment: @Gereon thanks for the reply. My role is AppManager, I cant see the questionnaire there... is it available only for admin?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be case. I see the button for the questionnaire in the projects where I'm admin, but not where I'm app manager.

Comment: Thanks mate... much appreciation.. cheers